# Web Services Security Authentication / Authorization

Tags: web-services

I work on a project website and I am about to develop a Web Service to a specific module of my project.

The problem is that I need to ensure the two concepts of authentication and authorization with the Web Service. I do not know how the web services technology provides the two concepts of security.

Please help me to advance, for your explanation and useful links, I'm really stuck

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each web service framework provides its own hooks to authenticate and to authorize.  So are you asking how to authenticate and authorize from a technical perspective?

I've only ever done Axis web services.  In that case, authorization could be handled declaratively in a WEB-INF/webservices.xml file.
Authentication is similarly handled - you configure a handler-class and implement the #handleRequest method, which is a called before the endpoint is reached.  At that point you can either get the encoded user:pass out of the HTTP header, or the SOAPHeader credentials, or whichever scheme you decide to use.

In the end, it's a technical question that is answered programmatically based on which frameork you use.

Answer (score 0):

Since web services are over HTTP you could use HTTPS and client authentication using X.509 certificates.
For authorisation you could use something as simple as username/password to map the user to specific priviliges.

Also you could look into SOAP's mechanisms for authentication using SOAP headers.
e.g. [SOAP auth](http://www.whitemesa.com/soapauth.html)